# Any utility in Linux to add item to the header of an existing email in a particular mailbox?

Tags: linux, command-line, email, sendmail

I am trying to add an extra header item to an existing email in a particular mbox, e.g.

> X-archived-to-crm: true,user,CRM-ID

after it was archived, the CRM-ID is basically the id in the DB of the CRM.

My MTA is sendmail, not sure whether this matters.

I had a look mail, mailx but cannot figure out how to do it.

I have been able to do this using Mutt in interactive mode, so there must be a way to do this from the command line.

Any (commandline) utility will do, it just needs to work non interactively.

Comment: Do you need to add this header to Mail as it is delivered, or are you trying to change the headers of an existing message in your mbox?  Either way, `procmail` is your friend.

Comment: @jsbillings I need to add this is to an existing email (message id is known) within a MBOX . There has to be a simple way of finding the message id and add one (or two) lines after that like 'X-archived-to-crm: true,user,CRM-ID'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done fairly easily with `perl -i` as an mbox file is just plain text.   There are various mbox manipulation library modules for perl, but something as simple as this doesn't need them.

The biggest difficulty is avoiding writing to the mbox file while something else is writing to it at the same time.

The script below uses the standard dotlock method of avoiding multiple simultaneous writers to the same mbox file (i.e. use `mboxfilename.lock`).

It should probably do flock and fcntl locking **in addition to** dotlock, to match whichever locking method(s) are used by your Mail Delivery Agent (MDA) and other programs that may be writing the mbox (e.g. `mutt` or other Mail User Agents (MUAs), or a Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) like `postfix` or `sendmail`, or a POP or IMAP daemon).

I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader - see the [File::FcntlLock](https://metacpan.org/release/File-FcntlLock) and [File::Flock](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Flock) perl library modules (there are also several similar modules with differing implementations of the same things, these are just the first I found).  You can install these on Debian (etc) with `apt-get install libfile-flock-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl`. Other distros probably have them or similar modules packaged.  Otherwise, install with `cpan`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak
#!/usr/bin/perl -i
# delete the first #! line if you don't want perl -i to create a .bak copy

use strict;
use Getopt::Std;

my %opts;
getopts('m:i:u:h', \%opts);

if ($opts{h}) {
  print "$0 <-m messsage-id> <-u user> <-i crmid> [mbox file...]\n";
  exit 1;
};

my $msgid = $opts{m} //  die "-m messsage-id is required\n";
my $user  = $opts{u} //  die "-u user is required\n";
my $crmid = $opts{i} //  die "-i crmid is required\n";

# I don't want to implement my own -i, so I'll just iterate
# over each file on @ARGV one at a time
my @files = @ARGV;

foreach my $mbox (@files) {

  # if the mbox is locked, then wait until it isn't.
  while (-e "$mbox.lock") {
    print "$mbox is locked!\n";
    sleep 1;
  };

  # lock it
  open(my $touch, ">", "$mbox.lock") || die "couldn't lock $mbox: $!\n";
  close($touch);

  @ARGV=($mbox);
  while (<>) {
    print;
    # case-insensitive match for "Message-ID" literal string,
    # case-sensitive for actual $msgid
    if (m/^(?:(?i)Message-ID:) <$msgid>/) {
      print "X-archived-to-crm: true,$user,$crmid\n"
    };
  };

  # remove the lock
  unlink "$mbox.lock";
}
```

Given the following mbox file:

```
From cas@example.org  Mon Aug 23 16:04:42 2021
Return-Path: <cas@example.org>
X-Original-To: cas@example.org
Delivered-To: cas@example.org
Received: by example.org (Postfix, from userid 1000)
        id 6B1DE3F2C; Mon, 23 Aug 2021 16:04:42 +1000 (AEST)
Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2021 16:04:42 +1000
From: Craig Sanders <cas@example.org>
To: Craig Sanders <cas@example.org>
Subject: test
Message-ID: <YSM6eiyrpvNKgxex@example.org>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Length: 56
Lines: 6

test messsage

craig

--
craig sanders <cas@example.org>
```

Running the following command:

```
$ ./insert-header.pl -m 'YSM6eiyrpvNKgxex@example.org' -i 99999 -u cas test.mbox
```

Results in the mbox file being changed to:

```
From cas@example.org  Mon Aug 23 16:04:42 2021
Return-Path: <cas@example.org>
X-Original-To: cas@example.org
Delivered-To: cas@example.org
Received: by example.org (Postfix, from userid 1000)
        id 6B1DE3F2C; Mon, 23 Aug 2021 16:04:42 +1000 (AEST)
Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2021 16:04:42 +1000
From: Craig Sanders <cas@example.org>
To: Craig Sanders <cas@example.org>
Subject: test
Message-ID: <YSM6eiyrpvNKgxex@example.org>
X-archived-to-crm: true,cas,99999
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Length: 56
Lines: 6

test messsage

craig

--
craig sanders <cas@example.org>
```

BTW, I also test this on a copy of my main mbox with:

```
$ ./insert-header.pl -m '.*' -i 99999 -u cas main.mbox
```

And it inserted the same `X-archived-to-crm` header in every message in the mbox.